# CSV Lookup to a String instead of an Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a variation of this question on [lookup in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852860/how-to-get-one-row-of-info-from-csv-file-with-powershell). The lookup is working, but how can I return a string into a variable instead of an object.  I tried doing |

```
$Test = @"
Name;property;location
n1;13;computer
n2;65;computer
n3;12;tablet
n4;234;phone
n5;123;phone
n6;125;phone
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -delimiter ';'

$lookupValue = "n2"
$result = $test | where-object Name -eq $lookupValue | Select-Object property 
Write-Host "Lookup: $lookupValue  Result: $result"
```

Current result:

```
Lookup: n2  Result: @{property=65}
```

Desired result:

```
Lookup: n2  Result: 65
```

I tried adding Out-String like this, but not desired results:

```
$result = $test | where-object Name -eq $lookupValue | Select-Object property | Out-String 
$result = Out-String | $test | where-object Name -eq $lookupValue | Select-Object property
```

Comment: Replace `Select-Object property` with `ForEach-Object -MemberName property` or `Select-Object -ExpandProperty property`

Comment: Thanks. Maybe add the -ExpandProperty to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69725903/how-can-i-pass-a-specific-item-property-to-a-variable-in-powershell, as it only suggests using SELECT OBJECT -PROPERTY which I tried.

Comment: Good call, I found a better duplicate (shows how to do it both with Select-Object, ForEach-Object and member enumeration)